# Using Indirect function in Data Validation through VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the indirect function in my excel sheet through VBA , I am getting an error when I try to substitute the cell address in.

```
=indirect(F5)
```

I am not able to substiture the "F5" with a variable here is my code.

```
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=indirect(F5)"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Comment: "=indirect(" & Variable_Name & ")" to use a variable if you pass a range use range("A1:B200").address

Comment: @99moorem Not working , just now tried, getting error 1004, object defined error

Comment: IT WORKS!!! thank you... I cocked up the first time.. Can you post that as an answer so i can close this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a range

```
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(""" & Range("F5").Address(False, False) & """)"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Comment: I have a problem, if you do it manually, you get an error from Excel, we click ok and it works, but in VBA  , the above code works only when the "indirect reference" has something selected. For example if have to select something from the first drop down for this to work , any workaround to this?

Comment: you could add an if statement before to check if the drop down is empty and if it isnt you could add the validation if it is just do the delete part of the validation

Comment: The problem is that , i want it to be empty. Not the other way round. Its throwing error if its empty :-(