# Excel VBA drop down list from named range

Tags: vba, excel, drop-down-menu

Similar problem: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455822/using-indirect-function-in-data-validation-through-vba)

I have this code, where I want to create a drop down list, say in Range B1:B2, where the list is dependent on some named ranges given in A1:A2.

[image]

```
Sub asdf()


    With Range("B1:B2").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(INDIRECT(""RC[-1]"",0))"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Problem is this gives me the error

> Run time error 1004' (Application defined or object defined error)

and when I click debug the following line is highlighted

```
   .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(INDIRECT(""RC[-1]"",0))"
```

The code actually has run a couple of times, I have no idea why. But then only the first cell A1 gets a dropdown list with correct values from the named range - while the cell A2 is a dropdown list with no values (all named ranges work, I've checked)

**EDIT** 
I think I located part of the problem, although this does not explain my problems with running the code. (forgive the non-English version of my Excel, but you might recognize this as the "Name Manager" inside "Formula"). The code is basically exactly the same as the code I get from the Macro Recorder, so this should work, should it not? Some of my named ranges has Value {...}. Why is this? The Named Ranges refer to the correct cells, but the cell values are empty...

[image]

**EDIT2**

It seems that you do not get the values for the cells you choose for a named range, when the cells are separated. This is so messed up... Is there a away around this?

Comment: This code runs fine for me. (although I altered to specify the worksheet in the with statement). Are you sure the names in the spreadsheet are the same as the named ranges - also the third code box (debug high-lighted code) contains an asterisk at the end; you may have a typo?

Comment: removed the asterix. Using **With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B2").Validation** does nothing for me unfortunately... this is so weird

Comment: @Flephal : maybe you recognize the problem from my EDIT?

Comment: @Flephal : how exactly did you alter the code?

Comment: How this code works when I generate it with the Macro Recorder, and not when ececuting the code, can anybody please explain me?