# Data validation using formula Indirect reference

Tags: excel, vba, list, validation

I have a following code recorded but if i run it from VBA it is throwing me an error (2nd line). You can do it manually but it gives you the warning and if you proceed with the warning then it takes the formula in Data validation.

```
     With .Range("F13").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(E13)"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

E13 is initially empty , it is a user selectable list.

Comment: By "manually" you mean with the GUI? What warning do you get when doing it manually? Is this all the code that the recording generated?

Comment: Yes , I just edited the by removing .selection etc but there is no code for warning message recorded.

Comment: i find similar problem specified here but i dont know how they solved ....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455822/using-indirect-function-in-data-validation-through-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `E13` is empty, then `Formula1:="=INDIRECT(E13)"` results in `#REF!` error. That's why the runtime exception in `VBA`.

The error also occurs in `GUI` but the `GUI` only warns and then ignores the error. `VBA` does not ignoring the error.

So we need to avoid this  `#REF!` error. To do so we can use

```
Formula1:="=IF(E13="""",A100000,INDIRECT(E13))"
```

Now `E13` can either be empty or must contain a correct reference string (address or name) which is resolvable using `INDIRECT`. If `E13` is empty. then `A100000`will be the list reference. So `A100000` should be a cell which is empty in every cases.

Comment: But it creates one more problem..now users can input their own input in these cells..data validation doesn't protect the cells. any workaround?

Comment: Yes, as long as `E13` is empty, the data validation doesn't protect the cells. But if `E13` contains a correct reference string (address or name) which is resolvable using INDIRECT, then it does. You could checking wheter `.IgnoreBlank = False` will suffice your requirements.