# List validation for a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set list validation for a cell via VBA.

I use a Formula1:= when the formula is a string.

When I try to use & to combine variables, it is giving me a 400 error.

The issue with the version of Formula1 with concatenated variables seems to be that the reference cell has an #N/A value. The written formula doesn't have that problem.

```
Sub InsertRow()

    r = Worksheets("Kickoff Schedule").UsedRange.Rows.Count + Worksheets("Kickoff Schedule").UsedRange.Rows(1).Row - 1
    ...

    With Range("E" & r).Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Formula1:="=INDIRECT($D" & CStr(r) & ")"
    End With

End Sub
```

Full list of things I've tried and if they have/haven't worked:

```
' Works:
Formula1:="=INDIRECT($D19)"

' Works:
MsgBox "=INDIRECT($D" & CStr(r) & ")"
' MsgBox shows =INDIRECT($D19) , as expected

' Doesn't work:
Formula1:="=INDIRECT($D" & CStr(r) & ")"

' Doesn't work:
Formula1:="=INDIRECT(""" & Range("D" & r).Address(False, False) & """)"

' Shows one option with a string of the right formula, as expected:
Formula1:="INDIRECT($D" & CStr(r) & ")"
```

I have already read [Using Indirect function in Data Validation through VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455822/using-indirect-function-in-data-validation-through-vba)

Comment: What do you mean by "the reference cell has an #N/A value, but the written formula doesn't have that problem?"

Comment: The cell D19 evaluates to #N/A. When I use Formula1:="=INDIRECT($D19)", the VBA can handle the fact that D19 is #N/A perfectly fine (it just has a dropdown with no options). When i use Formula1:="=INDIRECT($D" & CStr(r) & ")", I get a 400 error.

Comment: I'm confused - why are you trying to use `INDIRECT` on a cell that evaluates to `#N/A`?

Comment: It usually doesn't evaluate to that - it just temporarily does because the formula in D is referencing a blank cell after the row insertion (code in the ...)

Comment: Trying to replicate this: when the cell in column D evaluates to `#N/A` - I just used `=NA()` as a test - the whole thing throws a 1004 run-time error whether you use an entire formula, e.g. `"=INDIRECT($D19)"`, or concatenate `r` in.

Comment: What formula are you using in `D19`?

Comment: ="Ref!$G$"&INDEX(Ref!$J:$J, MATCH($B19, Ref!$I:$I, 0))&":G$"&INDEX(Ref!K:K, MATCH($B19, Ref!I:I, 0))

Comment: Replicating that exact formula, if the formula evaluates successfully, I can add the validation with either `"=INDIRECT($D19)"` or `"=INDIRECT($D" & r & ")"`. I get a run-time error if the formula is `#N/A`, which makes me think you need to fix that first before trying to add validation.

Comment: I am only getting an error with the latter of those two options, which is strange...

The challenge is, there's a blank cell requiring the user to select a value from a dropdown that will inform the formula in D. I want it to start as blank. I'd rather not create a fake or arbitrary default selection just so that formula looks like what it normally will. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use the INDIRECT function in VBA to create a formula or cell reference from text.  Just do this:

```
Formula1:="=$D" & CStr(r)
```